# 500 Internal Server Error - when I create new test plan

Tags: kiwi-tcms

in my product.py, I changed DEBUG=True. but in my browser, I still don't see error logs.

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkCMS.png)

I'm able to login. but the site throws a 500 internal error when I create a test plan. Errors also got thrown when I open test plans - logs are linked below

- 500 11938 "https://kiwi.dev.identos.ca/plan/search/?author__username__startswith=admin" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36"

I realized the log is not very useful.

Can you please give me instructions on how to properly turn on debug mode. I'm new to this product. All docs I'm reading just said "change DEBUG to True", without any instruction of where  and how to change it.

fyi, I'm using kiwitcms/kiwi:latest. The way I tried to turn on debug mode is - deploy and exec to docker image. and use `vi` to change DEBUG=True in product.py, but it didn't work.

Much Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Can you please give me instructions on how to properly turn on debug
> mode.

The official documentation should help:
https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing_docker.html#customization

> The way I tried to turn on debug mode is - deploy and exec to docker
> image. and use `vi` to change DEBUG=True in product.py, but it didn't
> work

If you insist on editing the file in-place then you must know that the changes are:

1. Reflected in the top-most container layer, which is a copy-on-write layer. That gets discarded when you turn-off the container and
2. Kiwi TCMS needs to be restarted in order to reflect the new settings, see 1).

This can be overcome by committing the changes from the COW layer into same/new container image, see
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/

Comment: Hi Alex. Thanks for replying and please forgive my limited python knowledge. I have 2 questions. 

1).What do I need to put into that local_settings.py file?  is it simply one line of code `DEBUG=True` ? or I need to copy all content from product.py and change the value of DEBUG?

2). how do I restart Kiwi?